# Validation in Jquery ajax form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, ajaxform

I am trying to validate user to enter a unique mobile number and email id.
It is checking and showing result mobile/email exist or not but if it exists still the form is submitting. Since I am new to jQuery validation I am not able to figure out how I should do it correctly nor can I find a perfect tutorial to do it in a right way.

Here is my code, I know lots of mistakes would be there and I apologize  for those small mistakes.

On my form I have given On blur function to check mobile number and email

From these two functions I am checking in database if exist or not

```js
function check_availability() {
  //get the mobile number  
  var main = $('#main').val();

  //use ajax to run the check  
  $.post("tutor/check_mobile", {
      main: main
    },
    function(result) {
      //if the result is 1  
      if (result == 1) {
        //show that the username is available 
        $('#mobile_availability_result').html(' ');
      } else {
        //show that the username is NOT available  
        $('#mobile_availability_result').html('Mobile Number already registered ');
      }
    });

}

function email_availability() {
    //get the email

    var main = $('#email_tuitor').val();
    //$email = urldecode("[email]") 


    //use ajax to run the check  
    $.post("<?php echo base_url(); ?>tutor/check_email", {
        main: main
      },
      function(result) {
        //if the result is 1  
        if (result == 1) {
          //show that the username is available 
          $('#email_availability_result').html(' ');
        } else {
          //show that the username is NOT available  
          $('#email_availability_result').html('Email already registered ');
        }
      });
  }
```

This is the jquery ajax form submission is it possible to do every validation on blur ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.error').hide();
  $("#next_tutor").click(function() {
    $('.error').hide();
    var main = $("#main").val();
    if (main == "") {
      $("label#main_error").show();
      $("input#main").focus();
      return false;
    }
    var name = $("#name").val();
    if (name == "") {
      $("label#name_error").show();
      $("input#name").focus();
      return false;
    }
    var email_tuitor = $("#email_tuitor").val();
    if (email_tuitor == "") {
      $("label#email_tuitor_error").show();
      $("input#email_tuitor").focus();
      return false;
    }
    var password_tuitor = $("#password_tuitor").val();
    if (password_tuitor == "") {
      $("label#password_tuitor_error").show();
      $("input#password_tuitor").focus();
      return false;
    }

    var tutor = $("#tutor").val();
    //  Returns successful data submission message when the entered information is stored in database.
    var dataString = 'main=' + main + '&name=' + name + '&email_tuitor=' + email_tuitor + '&password_tuitor=' + password_tuitor + '&tutor=' + tutor;
    // AJAX Code To Submit Form.
    //alert(dataString);
    //die;
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>tutor/tutor_sub_ses",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      success: function(result) {
        //alert(result);
        $("#abc").hide();
        $("#tutorreg2").slideToggle("slow").show();
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" action="#">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-8 text-center">
      <h2 class="text-warning">Tutor Registration</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" value="tutor" style="display:none" id="tutor">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name">
      <label id="name_error" class="error" for="name"><small style="color: red;">This Field Is Required</small>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" class="form-control phone" id="main" placeholder="Mobile Number *This will be the key to your account*" onBlur="check_availability()">
      <span id="mobile_availability_result"></span>
      <label id="main_error" class="error" for="main"><small style="color: red;">This Field Is Required</small>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email_tuitor" placeholder="Email" onBlur="email_availability()">
      <span id="email_availability_result"></span>
      <label id="email_tuitor_error" class="error" for="email_tuitor"><small style="color: red;">This Field Is Required</small>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password_tuitor" placeholder="Password">
      <label id="password_tuitor_error" class="error" for="password_tuitor"><small style="color: red;">This Field Is Required</small>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-8 text-right">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" id="next_tutor">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: What does your code do and how does it differ from what you want it to do? Are there any errors in the developer tools console?

Comment: No errors are there basically it is checking on blur if mobile number / email exist or not , if mobile number exist it should stop and dont allow user to submit form but here the form is submitting , so i want to validate form should not be submitted if mobile/email exist in my db . @JaromandaX

Comment: It is very difficult to help you with so much code you have provided. Try to create a fiddle/plunker to pin point your issue and we can help.

Comment: i just want to know how can i use onblur function to check from database if  email/mobile number exist or not how can i write in in jquery ajax form submission ? @ashfaq.p

Comment: Can you clarify how you submit the form?

Comment: $("#next_tutor").click(function() here i am calling ajax call to submit form in between this i want to do validation @NikolayErmakov

Comment: only i want to know how can i use onblur function under $(document).ready(function() so that when a user enter an email id/phonumber which exist in database it should validate @NikolayErmakov

Comment: @ashfaq.p only i want to know how can i use onblur function under $(document).ready(function() so that when a user enter an email id/phonumber which exist in database it should validate

Comment: You are already using a blur function and syntax is also correct. What is the issue with blur event ?

Comment: @ashfaq.p it is showing error message but still the form is submitting it should stop and ask user to enter a email/mobile which is unique , the form should not be submitted until he/she enters email/mobile which is present in database.

Comment: bro i accepted it i am new to this that's why but i accepted your changes @mplungjan

Comment: Rolled it back then. Also Please, no "bro" or "dude". I am not American

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quick way will be to use a global switch to enable sending the form. I would to it this way:

1. Create global variables with default values

   ```
   var mobileApproved = false, emailApproved = false;
   ```
2. Check status and prevent sending if value is false in click handler

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {

       ...


       $("#next_tutor").click(function() {

           if (!mobileApproved || !emailApproved) {
               return false;
           }
           ...
       })

       ...

   })
   ```
3. In your check functions manage approved status after each ajax response

   ```
   ...
   $.post("tutor/check_mobile", {
       main: main
   },
   function(result) {
       //if the result is 1  
       if (result == 1) {
           //show that the username is available 
           $('#mobile_availability_result').html(' ');
           mobileApproved = true;
       } else {
           //show that the username is NOT available  
           $('#mobile_availability_result').html('Mobile Number already registered ');
           mobileApproved = false;
       }
   });

   ...
   $.post("<?php echo base_url(); ?>tutor/check_email", {
       main: main
   },
   function(result) {
       //if the result is 1  
       if (result == 1) {
           //show that the username is available 
           $('#email_availability_result').html(' ');
           emailApproved = true;
       } else {
           //show that the username is NOT available  
           $('#email_availability_result').html('Email already registered ');
           emailApproved = false;
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: Just made it a bit shorter

Comment: i am trying to implement it

Comment: Sorry, a correction needed to `if (!mobileApproved || !emailApproved) {`. I updated the answer

Comment: super super super super woooohuu you did it bro today i learned new thing just because of you :) thanks a ton bro

Answer (score 1):

In order to stop the form from `submission`. You can keep a flag lets say `formvalid`.

Keep `formValid` as false initially. Based on your blur function, make it true if email and mobile are available else keep it false. In your form submission, put an if condition to check , if `formvalid` is true or not. If true then process with form submission else stop and throw error.

Comment: you are also perfectly right bro nikolay also explained me this thing